# How to insert text onto an entry box when a button is clicked

Tags: python, python-2.7, tkinter

Can anyone help me?

```
from Tkinter import *
import easygui

def whenoneclick():
    #How do I insert "1" into the Entry Label (inputbox)?


def mainfunc():
    inputvalue = inputvar.get()
    outputvalue = eval(inputvalue)

easygui.msgbox("The answer is: " + str(outputvalue), title="Answer")



maingui = Tk()


inputvar = StringVar()

inputbox = Entry(maingui, textvariable=inputvar).place(x=10,y=10)
inputbut = Button(text="=",command=mainfunc).place(x=10,y=40)

button = Button(text="1",command=whenoneclick).pack()
```

Please reply.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, to start, you need to make `inputbox` refer to the entrybox itself, not the return value of the `place` method (which is `None`).  This can be done by making the code like so:

```
inputbox = Entry(maingui, textvariable=inputvar)
inputbox.place(x=10,y=10)
```

Once this is done, you can use the entrybox's `insert` method. I wrote a simple script to demonstrate:

```
from Tkinter import *

root = Tk()

def click():
    inputbox.insert(0, "1")

inputbox = Entry()
inputbox.place(x=10,y=10)

Button(text="Click",command=click).place(x=10,y=40)

root.mainloop()
```

If you want to delete text, you can use the `delete` method:

```
inputbox.delete(0, END)
```

Comment: @user2863992 - I'm happy to have helped!  However, you shouldn't post an answer that just says "thank you" (because, technically, that isn't an answer).  Instead, you should accept an answer http://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers in order to keep SO organized (right now, your question is still in the "unanswered" bin).

Answer (score 0):

If you use a StringVar as per your code then you set the value

```
def whenoneclick():
    inputvar.set("1")  ## "1" not 1 because it is a StringVar
```

Note that you redefine here but it is local to the mainfunc function

```
def mainfunc():
    inputvalue = inputvar.get()
```

Also there is no mainloop in your program and "outputvalue" is local to the function so you will get an error on the easygui.msgbox, or indent the line so it is part of the function.